# PHP preg_replace_callback with more than one regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

Hello guys i have the follow code on php

```
return preg_replace_callback("#\{gallery: '(.+?)'\}#i", 
    function($i)
    { 
        $oGallery = new Gallery( $i[1] );
        $oGallery->PublicSide();
    }, $string);
```

Now i want to add the following to it:

Say that that i want to allow the user to choose if he wants to add directories to the gallery so i do:

```
"#\{gallery: '(.+?)' dir: '(.+?)')\}#i"
```

so the user has the potion to do: `{gallery: 'folder'}` or `{gallery: 'folder' dir: '1'}`

how would i go about doing this in terms of regular expressions so the replacement takes place even if the directory option isnt there? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it optional

```
"#\{gallery: '(.+?)'(?: dir: '(.+?)')?\}#i"
```

`(?:text)` creates a non-capturing group

adding `?` after the group makes it optional

Comment: One more question, this works on my PHP 5.3 localhost but it doesn't seem to work on my 5.2.17 server, seems to be something with the single quotes, any idea whats going on?